# AngularJS - input type="number" not clearable for non-number (NaN)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

### Clear number input type does not work for 'e' number

When I clear the input field with input eee in number type, it does not get cleared. Any other input numbers get cleared. Check the JSFiddle. Any hints would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ankx9up/

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" data-ng-model="searchAll"> 
    </input> 
    <a class="clear" href="" data-ng-click="clearSearch()">X</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
 app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.searchAll = "";
    $scope.clearSearch = function () {
       $scope.searchAll = "";
    };
});
```

Comment: Why are you allowing non-numeric values to be stored against `searchAll`? The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D) for `input[number]` states that AngularJS will throw an error underneath the hood if the bound value isn't a `number`. If you still need a work around, you can always modify the formatters and parsers of the binding—https://jsfiddle.net/1cxbnhv0/

Comment: You are right. I was hoping to see something out of the box to handle this case. I can always work around or have my own implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ng-model` directive is unable to clear the content of an `<input type="number">` element when that content parses to `NaN` (not a number). This can happen when a user pastes invalid content or simply types "eee".

One fix is to add a custom directive:

```
app.directive('clearNan', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        if (!value) elem.val(null);
        return value;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Usage:

```
<input type="number" clear-nan ng-model="x" />
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/9jGzkAR6rsUME2uJmSCe?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('numfmt-error-module', [])
.directive('clearNan', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        if (!value) elem.val(null);
        return value;
      });
    }
  };
})
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.typeOf = function(value) {
    return typeof value;
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="numfmt-error-module">
  <input clear-nan type="number" ng-model="x" />
  <br>
  {{ x }} : {{ typeOf(x) }}
  <br>
  <button ng-click="x=''">Clear input</button>
</body>
```